# If $f(x)$ is a real quartic polynomial $f'(x)$ has $\,3$ distinct real roots, what can we conclude about roots of $f(x)=k$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following question that says:

> Let $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ be a polynomial with $a,b,c$ and $d$ real. If $f'(x)$ has three distinct real roots, then
>
> > (a) there always exists a real constant $k$ such that $f(x)=k$ has exactly one real root,
> >
> > (b) there always exists a real constant $k$ such that $f(x)=k$ has three distinct real roots,
> >
> > (c) $f(x)=k$ has four distinct real roots for any real number $k$,
> >
> > (d) $f(x)=k$ has two real and two complex roots for any real number $k.$

Since $f'(x)$ has three distinct real roots , $f''(x)$ has 2  distinct real roots and $f'''(x)$ has one distinct real root. Now, $f'''(x)=6(4x+a)$ and so $f'''(x)=0 \implies x=-a/4 .$ Now,I am not sure what to do with it.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please improve the title to make it more informative.

Comment: Try drawing pictures to contradict some of the options.  To start, can you think of an example where $(d)$ is false?

Comment: The titles of your questions could use some help.  Rather than simply writing half of the first sentence of the problem, it would be more informative to those who see your question pop up on the main page if you could summarize the main idea behind the problem.  The new title given by Cameron is a great example because it communicates that you want to find information about the roots of a polynomial given information about the roots of its derivative. (...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) is false as witnessed by $f(x)=(x^2-1)^2$.

(b) quite interestingly is true: The three distinct (and simple!) roots of $f'$ correspond to local extrema, no saddle points. From the overall shape ($f(x)$ coming from $+\infty$ and  going to $+\infty$) we see that these extrema must be local min, local max, local min in that order. Let $k$ be the function value at the local max.

(c) is false, $f$ is bounded from below, pick $k$ smaller than the bound.

(d) is false for example for $k$ slightly smaller than the value chosen in (b)

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe it's worth pointing out that c and d are false regardless of the roots condition on $f'(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Only (b) is true. You may take $k$ to be the value of $f$ at the second root of $f'$. That root is a point of local maximum for $f$ and note that $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.